# How to send Id to Controller from Ajax Input Button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this grid which has an edit button. How do I add code to the input button so that the value of the Id is sent to the Controller?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditLineItem", "OrderSummary", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "content" })) {
<div id="summaryGrid">
    <table >
        <tr>
            <th>Report Type</th>
            <th>Borrower Name</th>
            <th>Property Address</th>
            <th>Est Comp Date</th>
            <th>Report Price</th>
            <th>Exp Fee</th>
            <th>Disc.</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
        </tr>
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    <td >@item.ReportName</td>
                    <td >@item.BorrowerName</td>
                    <td >@item.Address</td>
                    <td >@item.EstimatedCompletionDate</td>
                    <td >@item.ReportPrice</td>
                    <td >@item.ExpediteFee</td>
                    <td >@item.Discount</td>
                    <td >@item.TotalPrice</td>
                    <td >@item.Id</td>
                    <td ><input type="submit" value="Edit" /></td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table> 

</div>
```

}

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690413/post-button-in-grid/20690474#20690474

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit",new {@id=item.ID}) ` is along the right lines, but I need to do it via Ajax as I only want to update part of the page, not a full refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put a name on your input button.

```
<input type="submit" name="id" value="edit" />
```

Then on your action, you should be able to get the value for **id**.

If you want more complexity then you are going to have to rethink the way you are doing it. Most likely by writing your own JQuery methods.

```
$('input.edit').on('click', function (evt) {
   evt.preventDefault(); 
   var values = $(this).data();
   $.post($(this).attr('href'), values, function (result) { /*do something*/ });
 });
```

Html :

```
  <a href="/edit/1" class="edit" type="submit" data-id="1" data-method="edit" />
```

That's a start, but you could probably tweak it to fit your needs. At that point, you don't need to wrap the whole table with the **Ajax.BeginForm**.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Khalid's answer:  I tested with this form:

```
 <form method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="Id1" value="Edit" id="id1" />
    <input type="submit" name="Id2" value="Edit" id="id2" />
     <input type="submit" name="Id3" value="Edit" id="id3" />
</form>
```

The post looks like this when clicking on the third button:

```
http://localhost:34605/HtmlPage.html?Id3=Edit
```

In other words, the browser passes the name of whichever button is clicked.

This is an example of getting the Id in the controller:

```
if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys()) {
            string key = Request.QueryString.GetKey(0);

            int id;
            int.TryParse(key.Substring(2, 1), out id);

            Response.Write("You selected id: " + id);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have since found an even easier way of doing this:

Use the `<button>` element instead of `<input>`

With `<button>` you can do this:

```
 <button type="submit" value="@item.Id" name="id">Edit</button>
```

and then in the controller, all you need is this:

```
 public ActionResult EditLineItem(int id)
 { //Do something with id}
```

Note that this does not work with IE6.